# How to colour a specific border frame

Tags: graphics, mdframed, fbox

There is many help about how to insert frame for images and how to colour them, but I couldn't find anything about how to colour blue just the top frame, red the right-frame and so on. I would appreciate any clue, for example with `\fbox` or `mdframed`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of `tcolorbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} 

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
                  hbox,  
                  sharp corners, 
                  colback=white, 
                  colframe=white,  
                  borderline west ={0.5pt}{0pt}{blue}, 
                  borderline north ={0.5pt}{0pt}{red}, 
                  borderline east ={0.5pt}{0pt}{green}, 
                  borderline south ={3pt}{0pt}{yellow}]
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is the second question I have that `tcolorbox` answers, exceeding my expectations . I suspect it is a very fancy tool so I'm going to read more about it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm copy-pasting your code and I get a wider space on the right, I don't get why this happen.